# Indexing columns for joins

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, join, indexing

When we create an index on an attribute then we find records faster since the index is a tree and we navigate through the values which are in sorted order.
E.g. for `SELECT * from branches where name='Washington` via the index we will navigate in lexicographically order to reach the records in log time.
But when we index on columns we use in joins how does this work?
E.g.

```
SELECT BILLS.NAME NAME, BILLS.AMOUNT AMOUNT FROM BILLS,BANK_ACCOUNTS WHERE BILLS.ACCOUNT_ID = BANK_ACCOUNTS.ACCOUNT_ID
```

If we have created an index for `BILLS(ACCOUNT_ID)` and for `BANK_ACCOUNTS(ACCOUNT_ID)` how is the navigation faster? We just take each value of `BANK_ACCOUNTS.ACCOUNT_ID` and use the tree of the index for `BILLS` to find matching records?
If this is how it works then why do people usually recommend to create indexes in columns that are used in joins.
Seems to me that only 1 index is created and that would be for the table in the left-hand side of the equality comparator i.e. `BILLS`. Or am I wrong?

Comment: You should read [all of this](http://use-the-index-luke.com/) - Especially *The Join Operation* section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example code you provide perfomr an INNER JOIN between BILLS and BANK_ACCOUNTS, so only rows from BILLS that exist in BANK_ACCOUNTS will be returned. This is checked while the query is running, by performing the join only to the non-clustered index on BANK_ACCOUNTS, because all fields from BANK_ACCOUNTS that are referenced by the query (ie BANK_ACCOUNTS.ACCOUNT_ID) are part of the index, and thus "covered" by it.

Looking BANK_ACCOUNTS.ACCOUNT_ID in the index is O(log N), whereas scanning BANK_ACCOUNTS for each lookup would be O(N).

Does that help?

Comment: Not sure.`performing the join only to the non-clustered index on BANK_ACCOUNTS` This means that it ignores the table and only does a join on the index?

Comment: @Cratylus: Yes, that is what is meant by an index "covering" a query. That is to say, when reading the index record supplies all required fields for the query, the engine knows not to waste cycles reading the full record from the clustered index.